# How to read the dependency cycle log

Tags: rigging, constraints

[image]
I am building a rig and met a dependency cycle.
And I tried to read it from the system console.
The overall context is grasped, but I didn't realize what was going on specifically.
Things like `BONE_DONE()`, `BONE_READY()`, `BONE_POSE_PARENT()`, `Pose → Ready` are quite new to me.

Yes. The log seems simple and structured. However, I am a beginner.
So I hope someone can unravel the log and explain it in soft sentences.

Thanks in advance.